# Android.mki include execution sequence

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)  
TOP_LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)/../ 

#Add target arm version 
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi) 
MY_PJSIP_FLAGS := $(BASE_PJSIP_FLAGS) -DPJ_HAS_FLOATING_POINT=0 
else 
MY_PJSIP_FLAGS := $(BASE_PJSIP_FLAGS) -DPJ_HAS_FLOATING_POINT=1 
endif 

# Pjsip 
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjlib/build/Android.mk 
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjlib-util/build/Android.mk 

include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjnath/build/Android.mk 
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjmedia/build/Android.mk 
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjsip/build/Android.mk 

#pjsip JNI 
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/jni/build/Android.mk 

#JSON 
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/third_party/build/json/Android.mk 

#GSLB 
include $(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pgslb/build/Android.mk
```

There is an android Make file. Compile GSLB need this file. `libpjnath.a`, `libpjnath.a` is compiled by `$(TOP_LOCAL_PATH)/pjnath/build/Android.mk`. But the make file compile GSLB once execute. `libpjnath.a` can not be found.
How to designate the include execution sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, **ndk-build** runs *make*, and it's not a good practice to rely on the order in which make decides to build its targets. For example, it may launch parallel builds to use your multi-core CPU. The correct way is to explain to **make** that one target depends on another.

**LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES** and **LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES** are designed exactly for this purpose. See [NDK documentation](http://source-android.frandroid.com/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try add LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := pjnath in gslb. Hope helpful.

Comment: It should be `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES` for `libpjnath**.a**`.